# Google Maps setCenter(), v3, when click on element, with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When I using this code

```
<li latlon="58.55801847109299,11.244826413745159" class="point_on_map">Boviken, Hamburgö</li>
```

And this jQuery code:

```
$('.point_on_map').click(function(){
    var b = new google.maps.LatLng($(this).attr('latlon'));
    map.setCenter(b);
});
```

And when I click the center is in the blue, and the marker is in the left upper corner, and not draggable...
What have is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're actually doing there is passing one string to `LatLng` when you need to be passing it two. That comma in the `latlon` attribute doesn't get interpretted by JavaScript how you're thinking it does, it just gets seen as part of the string.

You need to split your `58.55801847109299,11.244826413745159` into two variables (e.g. `58.55801847109299` and `11.244826413745159`) and pass them separately to `LatLng`. e.g.

```
var latlon = $(this).attr('latlon');
var latlon_array = latlon.split(',');
var lat = latlon_array[0];
var lon = latlon_array[1];
var b = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
```

That's untested code but hopefully you get the idea.